# 'whoami' does not work on mac terminal

Tags: macos, node.js, unix, sudo

When I set up Node js environment, I often encounter npm permission error, as it can't access /node-modules/. With the help of this question ([npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)), I managed to change the ownership. However, I had to type my username, instead of 'whoami' as in the example.

```
sudo chown -R 'whoami' ~/.npm
chown: whoami: illegal user name
```

Does it mean 'whoami' is not supported on mac, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have a typo: you need to use backward ticks

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
```

Comment: many thanks, ChristianF. I never thought they would be backward ticks.