# git pull error "insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects"

Tags: git

I am trying to git pull but i am getting

**

```
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
fatal: failed to write object
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

**

I have tried various things toi change owner permission like this but no awail.

```
 sudo chown -R $USER:$USER "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git"
```

any suggestion will be appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: None of the answers from http://stackoverflow.com/q/6448242/6309 help?

Comment: actually i checked many answers but finally this one worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913218/whoami-does-not-work-on-mac-terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking many answers i finally got the solution by following this link ['whoami' does not work on mac terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913218/whoami-does-not-work-on-mac-terminal)